# Why does vtkImageStencil.SetInputData() give and argument error?

Tags: python, vtk

I am trying to use vtkImageStencil in python.
I am using the standard pip package "vtk 8.1.1"

```
import vtk
stencil = vtk.vtkImageStencil
image = vtk.vtkImageData()
stencil.SetInputData( image )
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-89-52c6c4badec2>", line 1, in <module>
stencil.SetInputData( image )
TypeError: no overloads of SetInputData() take 0 arguments
```

This does not make sense to me. Am I passing the wrong type?
Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake, do not forget the parentheses when creating an object.
Change the example to:

```
stencil = vtk.vtkImageStencil()
```

This happens, when converting c++ code to python code.